# Why are the indices of the arraylist added to the arraylist itself?

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm writing a script that dynamically generates to the screen a list of AD sites that happen to contain Exchange servers (specifically, using `Get-ExchangeServer | % {Get-ADSite $_.Site} | Sort -Unique`) and that part works well enough when I generate that list like so:

```
function SiteChoiceMenu {
$sites = Get-ExchangeServer | % {Get-ADSite $_.Site} | Sort -Unique
$siteCount = $sites.count
$bullets = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList($null)

for ($i=0;$i -lt $siteCount;$i++) {
    $index = $i+1
    $bullet = "$index. " + $sites[$i].Name
    $bullets.Add($bullet)
}
foreach ($bullet in $bullets) {Write-Host $bullet}
$siteChoice = Read-Host "Enter choice"

if ($siteChoice -in 1..$siteCount) { $siteChosen = $sites[$siteChoice-1]; return $siteChosen }
}

$siteChosen
```

When I run this code, I have 5 sites that have Exchange servers, so it generates a list like this:

```
1. Site 1
2. Site 2
```

and so forth. When I write $siteChosen to the screen, the output looks like this:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5

Name                  HubSiteEnabled
Site1                 False
```

When I step into the code, I can see that "siteChosen" is set to the exact output above. When I look at my Arraylist, $bullets, it shows only the strings I expect it to show. Now, what I did try is using a normal array instead of an ArrayList collection object, it does not exhibit the behavior above. When I write out $siteChosen to the screen, it has just the site in it. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$bullets.Add($bullet)` returns the the index at which the object was added in the [ArrayList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.add(v=vs.110).aspx). Because you don't store it in a variable, the returned int is accumulated in the pipeline.

`$thorwaway = $bullets.Add($bullet)` will hide it.

This is just one of those things you have to watch out for when using .NET objects and methods.

Comment: Should add a new line with the $throwaway variable inside the foreach loop? Or just add the variable before I call the Add method?

Comment: Hmmm... I think I see, but when I add the variable to the line with my Add method, it still outputs the last index... It's odd because there are six indices (0-5), but only 5 sites.

Comment: Remember this: the 'return' statement is just a convenience keyword for us C/C++/C# programmers. In Powershell, a function doesn't 'return' one thing, but any number of objects. Any statement that isn't "captured" by a variable will be accumulated on the pipeline. This is why `$siteChosen` contained all those numbers, then the site you actually chose.

Comment: Huh, yeah. I didn't know that. I only wanted it to return the AD site. Interesting... Thanks again! I'll end up going with just a normal array then.